# Unable to conect Botium Live Chat with Google Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am using botium box community edition for google Dialogflow.
Steps:
1.Goto Botium box 
2.Click on the chatbot select the bot
3.click on live chat
and when I am trying to start conversation I am getting the following error

Google API is enabled private key is also created

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4Y4s.png)

Comment: Looks like there is no Dialogflow agent connected

Comment: Issue resolve...I had done silly mistake, Using different email id's in Google Dialogflow and in the google cloud services.